# Why single goroutine run slower than multiple goroutines when runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)?

Tags: go, goroutine

I just want to try how fast goroutine switch context, so I wrote the code below. To my surprise, multiple gorountines run faster than the edition that does not need to switch context (I set the program to run in only one CPU core).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    t_start := time.Now()
    sum := 0
    for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
        sum = 0
        for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
            sum += i
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("single goroutine takes ", time.Since(t_start))

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    t_start = time.Now()

    for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            sum := 0
            for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
                sum += i
            }
            defer wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("multiple goroutines take ", time.Since(t_start))
}
```

A single goroutine takes 251.690788ms, multiple goroutines take 254.067156ms

The single goroutine should run faster, because single goroutine does not need to change context. However, the answer is opposite, single mode always slower. What happened in this program?

Comment: This is neither the proper way to benchmark such stuff nor is your reasoning about what should run faster or slower sound. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Your two methods don't even do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I mean both parts do the same computing, but multiple goroutines needs context switch that takes some extra time.

Comment: Both finished 10 times 100000000 adds.

Comment: yea, but your concurrent version has extra allocations and GC, and the overhead of a waitgroup, and the overhead of a defer.

Comment: Your measurements contradict your conclusion. The version with a single goroutine *is* faster, by 3 milliseconds. Not that this is a statistically relevant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your concurrent version several things the non-concurrent version does, which will make it slower:

1. It's creating a new `sum` value, which must be allocated. Your non-concurrent version just resets the existing value. This probably has a minimal impact, but is a difference.
2. You're using a waitgroup. Obviously this adds overhead.
3. The `defer` in `defer wg.Done()` also adds overhead, roughly equivalent to an extra function call.

There may well be other subtle differences, too.

So in short: Your benchmarks are just invalid, because you're comparing apples with oranges.

More important: This isn't a useful benchmark in the first place, because it's a completely artificial workload.

Comment: Thanks a lot, they do have some different

Comment: The point about GC isn't justified here. There's no way that the Go runtime allocates an integer that's only used locally on the heap.